# `std::make_shared` fails for empty parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, shared-ptr

### Background

I have a variadic class template.

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Ts... values) {
        
    }    
};
```

Using this class, I can create objects with/without parameters.

```cpp
Foo<int> f1{1};
Foo<int, double> f2{1, 2.0};
Foo f3{};
```

I can even create a shared pointer.

```cpp
auto f4 = std::make_shared<Foo<int, double>>(1, 2.0);
```

### Problem

The problem arises the moment I want to create a shared pointer without parameters. Neither of these approaches work:

```cpp
auto f5 = std::make_shared<Foo>();
```

```cpp
Foo f5{}
auto f5_sharedPtr = std::make_shared(std::move(f5));
```

```
main.cpp:27:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_shared class Foo>()’
     auto f5 = std::make_shared<Foo>();
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:81:0,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:703:5: note: candidate: template std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...)
     make_shared(_Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:703:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

### Questions

1. Can someone explain what's going on here?
2. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Not sufficiently experienced to know, but have you tried `auto f5 = std::make_shared<Foo<>>();` to make it clear it's templated, but with no parameters? I wouldn't be surprised if that's needed in certain contexts. Also, would be helpful to tag with the specific version of the C++ standard you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `std::make_shared<Foo<>>()`

`Foo<int,double>` is a type, which is why `std::make_shared<Foo<int,double>>` works.

The problem is that `Foo`, without the `<>` is a template, and is not a type, and results in a compilation error.

Edit:

The code

```
Foo f3{};
```

is sort of a special case.  In this case, your are using the C++17 feature [Class Template Argument Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).  This deduces the type of `f3` as `Foo<>` This is also what lets you write

```
Foo f4{1, 2.0}
```

Which would deduce the type of f4 as a `Foo<int, double>`.

The cppreference page gives more examples of when this feature can be used

Comment: Could you explain why `Foo f3{};` works? (I'm not criticizing, this is just not something I know the details of, and it would be useful to know why some contexts require the empty `<>` and some don't)

Comment: Also, if this is the reason then that compiler error message was pretty unhelpful ...

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Dave S's answer, I'd like to add that it is possible to write a version of `std::make_shared()` that works as you expected it to.

The trick is to make the "type" parameter of `shared_ptr<>` be a type template, and realize the type within the function.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>


template<template<typename...> typename T, typename... ArgsT>
auto my_make_shared(ArgsT&&... args) {
    // Create a type from T template according to what's in the arguments
    using ResT = T<std::decay_t<ArgsT>...>;

    // Now that we have a type instead of a template, we can call std::make_shared()
    return std::make_shared<ResT>(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Ts... values) {}    
};

void foo() {
    auto tmp = my_make_shared<Foo>(1, 2.0, "aaa");
}
```

Obviously, that function only works with templated types.